# Is it possible to call a method in dll inside OSB

Tags: dll, soa, kentico, osb

I am developing a new OSB service to replace an old .NET service.
The service has Kentico CMS as a backend and it's currently calling it using a dll provided by Kentico to call -for example- GetUserProfile (i.e. the dll is included inside the old service and its methods are called directly)

Is it possible to include a dll in OSB -or refer to it- ? this will need a setup for the .NET platform as I understand -I don't have mush knowledge in .NET-
(kindly provide a reference for your answer as I didn't find)

The other alternative is to ask the backend to provide a Webservice instead that I can consume, I need to know the answer for the previous question to decide.

I am using OSB 12c

Answer (score 1):

The [Kentico Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-kentico-api-externally) has information regarding connecting your external application to Kentico.

The short and sweet is:

1. Connect to the Kentico database - in your web.config or app.config add a connection string element and ensure it's named `CMSConnectionString`
2. Integrate the Kentico API libraries - add the Kentico.Libraries NuGet package to your solution
3. Initialize the Kentico application - in the `Global.asax` execute the `Application_BeginRequest` event

Comment: but my application (OSB) is java not .NET and is not on the same network as Kentico (i.e. doesn't have direct connection to the DB) , and this is my problem !! the old system that I want to replace doesn't have this constraint

Comment: thank you for the reference, I checked the documentation, and I think this will be the appropriate solution :
https://docs.kentico.com/k11/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service
I will ask the Kentico owner to avail it as Rest Webservice

Comment: For Java application you are left either with Kentico REST or Kentico application developer could actually write a WebAPI https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/using-asp-net-web-api-with-kentico  tailored to your precise needs where he would set up endpoints and those would returned serialized objects you can process in your service...